# Have any animal been discovered which don't have any kind of symmetry?

Tags: zoology, symmetry

Bilateral symmetry is a common feature, yet we come across starfish that has rotational/circular symmetry.

But is there any animal that has no symmetry?

Comment: I suspect something like a sea sponge won't have any symmetry.

Comment: Starfish are also bilaterally symmetric as larvae and descend from bilateral ancestors.

Comment: Maybe the abalone family (Haliotidae), but I don't know whether the animal is symmetrical or life-stages.